# error building monotouch-bindings WEPopover sample for Release|iphone

Tags: xamarin.ios

Works fine on `Debug|iphone` build.

For `Release|iphone` I am getting following error:

> ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_WEPopoverContainerViewProperties in
>   /var/folders/t0/bmphw69x013_2my_9n4sds9c0000gn/T/tmp215a7ca2.tmp/libWEPopoverUniversal.a(WEPopoverContainerView.o)
>   and
>   /var/folders/t0/bmphw69x013_2my_9n4sds9c0000gn/T/tmp215a7ca2.tmp/libWEPopoverUniversal.a(WEPopoverContainerView.o)
>   for architecture armv7

No idea how to fix. please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Updated*

This has been fixed now, just update your monotouch-bindings repository and it should work.

*Old answer*

This looks like the native library is bad for some reason.

There is one workaround you can do:

- In the iPhone Application project options, set Devices: Universal and Deployment Target: 3.2
- In the iPhone Build project options, switch to the Advanced tab and select ARMv6 instead of ARMv7.

Comment: now, I am getting following error:
"error MT2002: Can not resolve reference: System.IntPtr MonoTouch.Foundation.NSString::CreateNative(System.String)"

Comment: @coderguy123: Sorry about that, the binding was built against the latest beta instead of stable release. It should be fixed now.